# Cross Farm Service Applications - Need a reference sheet or table

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, service-applications, farm

This is more of a lazy question I assume :) , but I get lost at times when trying to come up with a SharePoint 2010 solution to a particular business requirement essentially when it involves working on multiple farms with so many service applications provided by SharePoint.

I was wondering if someone has a link to some article or perhaps some reference sheet that lists down all SharePoint 2010 service applications and has check on what can be publish and consumed across multiple farms and the ones that can only run on a single server farm.

I do know about a few that scale across multiple farms like Search and User Profile , but it will be really helpful if we have a consolidated list of all service applications for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From TechNet: [Technical diagrams (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx)

See [Services in SharePoint 2010 Products](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=167092) and [Cross-farm Services in SharePoint 2010 Products](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=167095)